# Algolia js helper save url redirect from searched product back to search result

Tags: javascript, algolia

I wonder if there is a way I can save the search url/query form a search result so I can pass that to a product page so the user can go back to the previous page with the search result displaying.

My website works like this.
A user lands on my landing page where he or she can browse/search for products,

Eg simple a simple query "Macbook" with a "addNumericRefinement" to search for specific price.

When the search result now shows up a user can click on one of the products and be redirected to the product page. But if the user now goes back (clicking on the back arrow in browser) the user will get redirected to the landing page again, but now the search results is gone, so how can I store the search paramateres in eg my url so the user doesnt have to make a new search each time.

I have tried this:

```
searchIndex() {
      this.algoliasearchHelper.addNumericRefinement('state', '=', this.stateId);
      this.algoliasearchHelper.setQuery(this.query).search();

      var state = this.algoliasearchHelper.url.getStateFromQueryString(this.query);
      console.log(state);

    },
```

But I get the error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStateFromQueryString' of undefined**

I also tried:

```
var state = this.algoliasearchHelper.getState();
      var qs = this.algoliasearchHelper.url.getQueryStringFromState(state);
      console.log(qs);
```

but that also return a error: **Cannot read property 'getQueryStringFromState' of undefined**

So is there anyway to just update my browser url right away when I do a search? That way I dont have to pass the url between pages and can simply just hit the back button on the browser

Answer (score 0):

The url namespace is on the constructor not on the helper instance. You should do:

```js
algoliasearchHelper.url.getQueryStringFromState()
// and
algoliasearchHelper.url.getStateFromQueryString();
// Do not do: this.algoliasearchHelper
```